# DATUM now hiring - no skills required

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

Please remove the **Skills we're looking for:** when there aren't any...or did the company forget to put the skills in?

[image]

Comment: Would it be better to have `Skills we're looking for: None`?

Comment: @NathanOliver - why would you ever do that?

Comment: The title of this post reads like spam, I was ready to flag it ;-)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - I'm glad I got your attention...now work for DATUM!

Comment: @JonH I can't, I'm not proficient enough in

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - thanks for the laugh that was great.

Comment: What if they're looking for someone who has a job available? *I'll walk myself out*

Comment: I think that ad has insufficient datum.

Comment: I think I have I might have the right qualifications for that job:-).I shall apply to their Full Stack Developer role and use text files to create websites and store their sensitive data. More seriously, I think this is a genuine company and looking at their websites they do advertise for developer roles that require C#, ASP.NET and SQL Server skills, so it seems they just forget to include them or are simply advertising for a wide range of jobs.

Comment: @Jaco I don't think "1 job available" is a "wide range of jobs" ;)

Comment: You are right @DavidPostill job, they are just hiring for one full stack developer with no skills:-).

Comment: Damn, I know lots of people with no skills, but they all live in the US.

Comment: This is the funniest post on Meta in a long time (including the comments).

Comment: It looks like you must have 1 job available to get this job

Comment: I can´t see any use for a job that has no requirements at all, thus the feature itself would be useless. I doubt there are many of those posts around stack.

Comment: In News today...DATUM most popular job to have.

Comment: I kinda say leave it as it is. It lets you know how careful (or not) the company are when posting jobs.

Comment: they're looking for people skilled in "no data to monitor", it seems a kind of "NoSQL" expert

Comment: @BilltheLizard hey, I resemble that remark

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out. We've updated this so if there aren't any skills or benefits listed by the company, these sections will be hidden.